# what is the right way to plot a histogram in python using pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have seen two methods online, but after trying the two methods you'd think the plots should look the same, but they do not.

Method1:

```
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(SP[0], 30, facecolor='green', alpha=1, histtype='stepfilled')
```

[image]

Method2:

```
counts, bins = np.histogram(SP[0])
plt.hist(bins[:-1], bins=30, weights=counts)
```

[image]

Comment: The input seems to be discrete, while the `plt.hist` is meant for continuous data. Therefore, your first histogram is malformed. For your second plot, except for using the wrong `bin=` parameter, in case you really want to use `weights=` you'd get a problem with rounding.

Answer (score 1):

The two methods do completely different things. Method1 is the correct one. `plt.hist()` calculates the histogram of its first argument and plots the result.
There simply is a mistake in method2. You first calculate your histogram via `np.histogram()` and then plot the results. But you don't use `plt.hist()` in the second step. If you do so, you will plot the histogram of the bins of the resulting histogram of the function call before. Instead, you just use `plt.plot()` or `plt.step()`. I would suggest you use:

```
counts, bins = np.histogram(SP[0], bins=30)
plt.step(bins[:-1], counts, where='post')
```

Comment: one could also use `plt.bar` to plot the result of `np.histogram`